# How to resize div1 while dragging div2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

[enter link description here][1]Hi..

Here m doing something like meter.. I need to create resizable div. and the div needs to be rise the size upward when I drag div2..

Pls check the link to see what m trying..

Here when I drag the red bar half of the way the color in A2 should rise, when I drag second half the A1 color should rise..

The similar way B & C ..

```
<div id="vbar">
<div id="hbar">
</div>

<div id="A11"></div>
<div id="A1">A1</div>
<div id="A12">A12</div>
<div id="A2">A2</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EM2v3/1/

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the code that you have tried

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please show us some code, and what you've tried so far (and why it hasn't worked). I recommend using http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript to give action to your barchart.

Here's a quick and crude outline of a home-made slider controlling a bar to get you started.

- Add 2 divs to be your slider control: a thumb-div inside a container-div
- Add another div to be the bar for your barchart
- Using CSS, absolutely position the thumb relative to its container
- Listen for drags by the user (==mousedown+mousemove)
- Reposition the thumb based on how far the use has dragged
- Change the bar based on the position of the thumb

[image]

Here's code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wgMyW/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{
        position:relative;
        border:1px solid red;
        width:300px;
        height:30px;
    }
    #thumb{
        position:absolute;
        border:1px solid blue;
        width:20px;
        height:30px;
        background:blue;
    }
    #bar{
        position:absolute;
        top:300px;
        left:10px;
        background:green;
        width:50px;
        height:30px;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var $thumb=$("#thumb");
    $thumb.pos=0;
    $thumb.maxX=$canvas.width()-$thumb.width();
    $thumb.percent=function(){
        return($thumb.pos/$thumb.maxX);
    }

    var $bar=$("#bar");
    $bar.baseY=200;
    $bar.maxHeight=150;

    // start at 50%
    setValue($thumb.maxX/2);

    var isDown=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      var dx=mouseX-startX;
      var dy=mouseY-startY;
      startX=mouseX;
      startY=mouseY;

      setValue($thumb.pos+dx);

    }

    function setValue(value){

        $thumb.pos=Math.min(Math.max(value,0),$thumb.maxX);

        var height=$bar.maxHeight*$thumb.percent();

        $thumb.css({
            "left":$thumb.pos
        });

        $bar.css({
            "top":$bar.baseY-height,
            "height":height
        });
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas">
        <div id="thumb">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery UI. [jQuery UI - resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#synchronous-resize)